# Javascript return statement error

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, return

This is my original code it is a cache using jquery deferreds/promises

```
var templateCache = {};

var retrieve = function (templateURL) {
    if (!templateCache[templateURL]) {
        templateCache[templateURL] = $.get(templateURL);
    }
    return templateCache[templateURL];
};
```

I wanted to try to change it to a one liner so i made

```
var templateCache = {};
var retrieve = function( templateURL ){
  return templateCache[ templateURL ] || templateCache[ templateURL ] = $.get( templateURL );
}
```

But I keep getting an error that the left hand side of the return statement is invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`||` has a higher precedence than `=`.

Your code is being parsed as `(a || b) = c`, which doesn't make any sense.

You need to add parentheses to force the assignment to happen first:

```
a || (b = c)
```

Answer (score 5):

Add some brackets around the assignment

`return templateCache[ templateURL ] || (templateCache[ templateURL ] = $.get( templateURL ));`

Answer (score 1):

here is another way to write it using a ternary operator.

```
var retrieve = function( templateURL ){
    return templateCache[ templateURL ] ? templateCache[ templateURL ] : templateCache[ templateURL ] = $.get( templateURL );
};
```